# SSIS 2012 OLE DB vs EXCEL dynamic worksheet creation

Tags: excel, ssis, oledb

I have a Web Service call that returns reporting data using Linq-To-Entity (strongly type class list). I connected this task to a foreach loop container with a Execute SQL Task. I have come to a crossroad as to what approach I should take on whether the OLE DB connection or to use EXCEL. The server [W2k8 R2] does not have Excel installed (we want to avoid that as much as possible).

15 worksheets would have the same schema info (each sheet is a per client basis) while the last worksheet is a summary and has a different schema. The summary has its own strongly typed class as well.

The end goal is to pass that report data into the xlsx file then to an SMTP task as an email attachment.

Would I be better off creating the Excel Tables in a script task using OLE DB or using EXCEL connection?

Using SSIS with SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at report subscription and delivery with SQL Server Reporting Services. Might be an easier and more maintainable way to implement your requirement [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762).

Not sure what you mean by an EXCEL connection, but if it's the connection manager in SSIS, then an EXCEL and OLEDB connection are practically the same thing. The EXCEL connection manager uses the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet 4.0 [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).